# How do I set up Code::Blocks build options to run plplot?

Tags: codeblocks

I cannot find any documentation on how to setup Code::Blocks to run plplot. I have installed plplot version 5.14.0 in /home/myname/plplot. I followed instructions on to compile at https://sourceforge.net/p/plplot/wiki/Linux/. That went smoothly, and I have a folder for build_directory and install_directory in plplot folder. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

When I go to compile an example program in Code::Blocks, I do not know which files or folders need to be added into Project->Build Options. The error message reads: Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘plplot.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory

Here is the example I am trying to compile:

```
program ft_x00f
! This is a modified version of x00f.f90
! which was written by Alan Irwin

   use plplot
   implicit none

   integer, parameter :: NSIZE = 100
   real(kind=plflt), dimension(0:NSIZE) :: x, y
   real(kind=plflt) :: xmin = 0.0_plflt, &
                       xmax = 1.0_plflt, &
                       ymin = 0.0_plflt, &
                       ymax = 100.0_plflt

   integer :: i

! Prepare data to be plotted.
! x = .00, .01, .02, ..., .99, 1.00
   x = [(i, i=0,NSIZE)] / real(NSIZE)
   y = ymax * x**2

! Parse and process command line arguments
   call plparseopts( PL_PARSE_FULL )

! Initialize plplot
   call plinit( )

! Create a labelled box to hold the plot.
   call plenv( xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, just=0, axis=0 )
   call pllab( "x", "y=100 x#u2#d", &
               "Simple PLplot demo of a 2D line plot" )

! Plot the data that was prepared above.
   call plline( x, y )

! Close PLplot library
   call plend( )

end program ft_x00f
```

Answer (score 0):

This one was painful, but I have found out the answer. First, I could not compile the above code even without Code::Blocks. I suggest copying a file directly from the plplot /examples directory and opening that in Code::Blocks. The best way to find out what commands are needed is to look at what plplot does when you issue the make command to compile the examples when installing plplot.

I then needed to add following to Code::Blocks -

1) Project -> Build Options -> Linker Settings -> Other Linker Options -lplplotfortran -lplfortrandemolib (Note, I knew these from the make command discussed above)

2) Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories -> Compiler /install_directory/lib/fortran/modules/plplot

3) Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories -> Linker /install_directory/lib

This will at least compile and run an example. I am sure more fun awaits for creating my own programs. Good luck to all.